# Unity Swipe Inputs using Coroutines

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch

I am Using the following lines of code to accurately detect swipes in four directions but I don't understand why it does not work Please Help

```
void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Joystick1Button9))
        Application.Quit();
    Dictionary<int, Touch> touch = new Dictionary<int, Touch>();
    foreach (Touch t in Input.touches)
    {
        Vector2 Direction = new Vector2(0,0);
        switch (t.phase)
        {
            case TouchPhase.Began:
                touch[t.fingerId] = t;
                Swiped = false;
                break;
            case TouchPhase.Ended:
                if (touch.ContainsKey(t.fingerId))
                {
                    Direction = t.position - touch[t.fingerId].position;
                    Direction = Direction.normalized;
                    Swiped = true;
                }
                else
                    Swiped = false;
                break;
            default :
                Swiped = false;
                break;
        }
        if (Swiped)
        {
            if (Vector2.Dot(Direction,Vector2.up) > Mathf.Sqrt(1/2f))
            {
                GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Light>().color = Color.red ;
                RandomObjects();
            }
            else if (Vector2.Dot(Direction, -1*Vector2.up) > Mathf.Sqrt(1/2f))
            {
                GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Light>().color = Color.green;
                RandomObjects();
            }
            else if (Vector2.Dot(Direction, Vector2.right) > Mathf.Sqrt(1/2f))
            {
                GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Light>().color = Color.blue;
                RandomObjects();
            }
            else if (Vector2.Dot(Direction,-1 * Vector2.right) > Mathf.Sqrt(1/2f))
            {
                GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Light>().color = Color.yellow;
                RandomObjects();
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

As suggested I Stopped using Coroutine and wrote the code in the Update() Method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are number of problems in your code:

1. The code is not working because you don't call `Input.GetTouch()` again after `WaitForSeconds`.
2. It's **not an accurate swipe detection**. Strictly speaking, it's not a swipe detection at all. If you double tap and hold your finger on second tap, your code will detect it as a swipe. While it's not. Also, gestures that last less than 0.5 seconds will not be detected. To make an accurate gesture detection you need to continuously analyze user's input.

So, it should be something like this:

```
const float swipeThreshold = 100.0f;

IEnumerator SwipeInput(Action<Vector2> onSwipe)
{
    Dictionary<int, Touch> activeTouches = new Dictionary<int, Touch>();
    Dictionary<int, Vector3> activeButtons = new Dictionary<int, Vector3>();
    while (true)
    {
        if (Input.touches.Length > 0)
            foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
                switch (touch.phase)
                {
                    case TouchPhase.Began:
                        activeTouches[touch.fingerId] = touch;
                        break;
                    case TouchPhase.Ended:
                        if (activeTouches.ContainsKey(touch.fingerId))
                        {
                            Vector2 delta = touch.position - activeTouches[touch.fingerId].position;
                            if (delta.magnitude > swipeThreshold)
                                onSwipe(delta);
                        }
                        break;
                }
        else
            for (int i = 0; i <= 2; ++i)
            {
                if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(i))
                    activeButtons[i] = Input.mousePosition;
                else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(i) && activeButtons.ContainsKey(i))
                {
                    Vector2 delta = Input.mousePosition - activeButtons[i];
                    if (delta.magnitude > swipeThreshold)
                        onSwipe(delta);
                }
            }
        yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
    }
}
```

P.S. Coroutines can look like cool thing to use. But don't use it for everything you can think of. Or you will end up fighting to synchronize them. Only use them when you really need them. I.e. when using them results in more clear, compact or elegant code. Gesture detection, for example, is not the case.

Comment: Sorry @Sergey Krusch its not Working

Comment: Works with mouse now.

Comment: I am testing it on Multi Touch Capable Blackberry Device

Comment: Can't test it on Blackberry, but it works on iPhone.

Comment: Show how you use `SwipeInput` method

Comment: Sorry Got it Since I Changed to Update Use of Dictionary reset it everytime the update was called Thanks @SergeyKrusch